# "Could not find or load main class jjtree"

Tags: java, windows, command-line

I'm trying to get started with Javac. I've installed the JDK, and it's in 
     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin

I've also added that path both to PATH and a new variable JAVA_HOME. The thing is I can't seem to use jjtree.

After doing some research I also downloaded the scripts that were missing from my version of the JDK, but that didn't change anything. Here's some of the folder contents:

[image: part of C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin]

Here is the error:
[image]

It's probably something simple, but I'd appreciate the help :)

Comment: Look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean). I think it is what do you need read the first.

Comment: @OtabekKasimov that was a lot of info, but I didn't get most of it :/ It's sorted now, thanks for the link :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the file seems to be a batch file or command script and not a proper exe file
can you try to open the file and see what is wrong with the script. possibly its a classpath issue

Comment: I was missing the bin\lib folder with javacc.jar in it, and the system variable CLASSPATH, so thanks for setting me on the right course!!